# Object Detection using Tensorflow and Python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection

I am following a youtube video which shows how to use tensorflow in Jupyter notebook for obstacle detection.

The video link is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U&t=7979s

GitHub files: https://github.com/nicknochnack/TFODCourse

I have run into an issue at 2:12 in the video. I have collected. my images and have labelled them accordingly, I am now trying to create a .record file, however this is not being created upon execution of the following lines of code, furthermore no error is given and I am running it on mac os.

```
import os

CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME = 'my_ssd_mobnet' 
PRETRAINED_MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8'
PRETRAINED_MODEL_URL =      'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz'
TF_RECORD_SCRIPT_NAME = 'generate_tfrecord.py'
LABEL_MAP_NAME = 'label_map.pbtxt'


paths = {
    'WORKSPACE_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace'),
    'SCRIPTS_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow','scripts'),
    'APIMODEL_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow','models'),
    'ANNOTATION_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace','annotations'),
    'IMAGE_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace','images'),
    'MODEL_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace','models'),
    'PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace','pre-trained-models'),
    'CHECKPOINT_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace','models',CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME), 
    'OUTPUT_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace','models',CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME,         'export'), 
     'TFJS_PATH':os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace','models',CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME, '       tfjsexport'), 
    'TFLITE_PATH':os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace','models',CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME, 'tfliteexport'), 
    'PROTOC_PATH':os.path.join('Tensorflow','protoc')
 }


files = {
    'PIPELINE_CONFIG':os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace','models', CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME,    'pipeline.config'),
    'TF_RECORD_SCRIPT': os.path.join(paths['SCRIPTS_PATH'], TF_RECORD_SCRIPT_NAME), 
    'LABELMAP': os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], LABEL_MAP_NAME)
}


 for path in paths.values():
     if not os.path.exists(path):
         if os.name == 'posix':
             !mkdir -p {path}
         if os.name == 'nt':
             !mkdir {path}

 if not os.path.exists(files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']):
     !git clone https://github.com/nicknochnack/GenerateTFRecord {paths['SCRIPTS_PATH']}

!python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x {os.path.join(paths['IMAGE_PATH'], 'train')} -l      {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'train.record')} 
!python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x {os.path.join(paths['IMAGE_PATH'], 'test')} -l {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'test.record')}
```

`

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how I can solve this issue.

Thanks

I was expecting the .record files to be created instantly as no error was given. I was thinking that maybe there is some sort of syntax error. I have also tried to see if the .record files are hidden but this is not the case.